# How do you debounce a function after the first call?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function similar to [debounce](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/debounce/), except I want the debounced function to be called immediately after the first call and all calls after the first call within the debounce time limit to be debounced. For example, if the function is hooked up to a button, and you rapidly and repeatedly click it 10 times, the function gets called on the first press and gets called a second time after x milliseconds have passed since the tenth press.

Comment: [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) gets you a time stamp - it should be simple to compare the timestamp of a call with the last timestamp that was let through - post a new question with details if you get stuck.

Comment: [This](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) is the article you're looking for. Because it's not always among the first when you search for *"debounce vs throttle"*, I use a small trick to re-find it. It's linked from both `_.debounce` and `_.throttle` documentation. You seem to look for `_.debounce` with `leading: true`. `_.throttle` is used when you want to not run a function more frequently than a set interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure JavaScript processing:**

Requiring a repeated call within the "debounce" period to be called in addition to the first call adds a complication that can be addressed using a timer in addition to timestamps to make immediate calls if possible.

However, because calls to a function may be delayed, it is not always possible to return a value from the function to the caller in real time.

The following concept code

- calls the process "lock" in the sense of locking out calls in a predefined way.
- returns `undefined` to all calls without implementing call backs to allow a caller to  tell if its call was actioned or not, or to retrieve a return value;
- When a call is made after a lockout period within which addition call attempts were made, the actual arguments used are to place a delayed call are those supplied by the most recent call attempt.

```js
function CallLock( toCall, lockout) {
    let argv;
    let lastCall = 0;
    let timer = 0;
    function recall() {
        timer = 0;
        lastCall = Date.now();
        toCall(...argv);
    }
    return function( ...args)  {
        let now = Date.now();
        if(timer == 0) {
            if( now >= lastCall+lockout) {
                lastCall = now;
                toCall( ...args);
            }
            else {
                argv = args;
                timer = setTimeout(recall, lastCall+lockout - now);
            }
        }
        else {
            argv = args; // use most recent arguments
        }
    }
}

// test CallLock
let start;
function demo( msg) {
   console.log( "demo('%s') called. Time is %sms after start", msg, Date.now() - start);
}

let lockDemo = CallLock( demo, 1000);   // 1 second lockout

start = Date.now();
lockDemo("call 1");
setTimeout( lockDemo, 200, "call 2");
setTimeout( lockDemo, 400, "call 3");
setTimeout( lockDemo, 1800, "call 4");
```

Test code uses a 1 second lockout time. Note that timer delays are inexact and Date.now() rounds to the nearest millisecond. The expected results are

1. call 1 is made synchronously and will show a start time of 0 or 1ms.
2. call 2 is never actioned - its arguments are not used.
3. call 3 is actioned, but delayed until shortly after the first call lockout
4. call 4 is actioned, but also delayed because the lockout period from when call 3 was actioned is still in effect.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle). check this article for [difference between throttling and debouncing](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/#article-header-id-0). if throttle isn't what you need, then you should implement what you need from scratch (and adding more explanation for the details).

---

Edit:
So, Yes, It is not throttle; It is debounce with invocation on leading edge in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce);

```
_.debounce(yourCallback, 100, {
  'leading': true
})
```

Comment: It's not throttle. Refer to the example in the original post

Comment: @Iamok yes that is not throttle, I'd updated the answer accordingly;

Comment: I am looking for an answer that does not involve installing dependencies, but you do have a solution

Comment: @Iamok Lodash supports tree shaking. so you can import [debounce implementation](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/debounce.js) independently , not adding whole library.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest don't go for debounce. The older debouncing technique relies on setTimeout which is not perfect. Instead try to make use requestAnimationFrame which has in built support for the next trigger for Dom visual states change.

Comment: You didn't understand requestAnimationFrame dude.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is for running animation frames at 60 fps...?

Comment: You should call this method whenever you're ready to update your animation onscreen. This will request that your animation function be called before the browser performs the next repaint.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do though?